# Using function calling to return a description and coordinates of building in OpenAI API?

Tags: python, openai-api

I want the chatgpt API to return a description and coordinates in lat/lng of a building whose details i enter in my area.

I can kinda get this working by writing a regular prompt and then using a regex to parse the data. This is a hack though and sometimes doesn't work.

I need to take advantage of chatgpt's function calling feature to quiz the API and get back a properly formatted response ie. description: 'here', coordinates: 'lat xx.xxx, lng: xx.xxx'

I've been trying to get this right all day and I can't seem to nail it. This is my non-working code...

```
def get_local_attractions(location, description, coordinates):
    """Get the location"""
    attraction_info = {
        "location": location,
        "description": description,
        "coordinates": coordinates
    }
    return json.dumps(attraction_info)


def run_query():
    # Step 1: send the query and available functions to GPT                                                                                                                                                                             
    messages = [{"role": "user", "content": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}]
    functions = [
        {
            "name": "get_local_attractions",
            "description": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "parameters": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "description": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                    },
                    "location": {"type": "string", "coord": coordinates},
                },
                "required": ["location"],
            },
        }
    ]
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
        messages=messages,
        functions=functions,
        function_call="auto",  # auto is default, but we'll be explicit                                                                                                                                                                 
    )
    response_message = response["choices"][0]["message"]

    # Step 2: check if GPT wanted to call a function                                                                                                                                                                                    
    if response_message.get("function_call"):
        # Step 3: call the function                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        # Note: the JSON response may not always be valid; be sure to handle errors                                                                                                                                                     
        available_functions = {
            "get_local_attractions": get_local_attractions,
        }  # only one function in this example, but you can have multiple                                                                                                                                                               
        function_name = response_message["function_call"]["name"]
        fuction_to_call = available_functions[function_name]
        function_args = json.loads(response_message["function_call"]["arguments"])
        function_response = fuction_to_call(
            location=function_args.get("location"),
            description=function_args.get("description"),
            lat=function_args.get("coordinates"),
        )

        # Step 4: send the info on the function call and function response to GPT                                                                                                                                                       
        messages.append(response_message)  # extend conversation with assistant's reply                                                                                                                                                 
        messages.append(
            {
                "role": "function",
                "name": function_name,
                "content": function_response,
            }
        )  # extend conversation with function response                                                                                                                                                                                 
        second_response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
            messages=messages,
        )  # get a new response from GPT where it can see the function response                                                                                                                                                         
        return second_response


print(run_conversation())
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: For a start I can't find the semantic label suitable for coordinates ie. Lat/Lng. ```"location": {"type": "string", "coord": coordinates},```